# solving the assignment problem for 3 groups instead of 2

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming

Let's say we have 3 groups of people each one with n people, I need to assign them to n groups of triplets such that each triplet is made out of 1 person from the first group, one from the second and one from the third.

There's also a cost function for each possible triplet and we need to pair them in a way that would minimize the sum of the costs.

If there were only 2 groups than that would be the [Assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

I thought of maybe using linear programming approach and give each triplet a variable and minimize the sum of weighted variables (according to the cost function) with the constraints that for each person the sum of the variables of the triplets his in would be 1 and each variable is between 0 and 1, but i'm not sure how to prove that there's an integer solution for that problem and if so how to find it.

Comment: This [link](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F0-306-48332-7_522) seems to suggest that the problem is NP hard.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem yes, I suspected that was the case. Kinda sucks, I wanted to use this for something related to building 3d-models from images but if it's NP-hard I guess it's impossible.

Comment: I don't know much about this specific problem, but there may be some good heuristic approximations. Here is one [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/171495?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) that comes up in Google search.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Do you know if this paper proofs a constant approximation for the problem? i.e. if the total cost of the heuristic approximation algorithm is at most some constant multiplied by the optimal cost. I want to know that in order to know if it's worth it to purchase that 30$ paper.

Comment: I quickly looked over the paper and it does not seem to provide a constant approximation result. They mostly focus on empirical performance of different combinations of heuristics. It might be a good idea to ask if such a bound is known on cstheory.stackexchange. You might also get better references.

Comment: Another helpful link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be many names for this problem: [three-index assigment problem](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F0-306-48332-7_522), [3-dimensional, or in general n-partite matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching). Although the problem is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching#Optimization_problem), as stated also in the comments above, moderately large instances can be solved quite efficiently using [(M)ILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) solvers.

Here is a 3-dimensional example using Python and PuLP. Moreover, the code can handle other dimensions `n>=2` by adjusting the dimension list `dims`. Naturally, both problem and solution can be visualized as an n-partite network.

[image: network]

```
# import modules
import copy
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pulp

# number of people (or items) per group (or dimension)
dims = [8, 4, 12]

# dummy weight array
# (one weight for each combination of people, with one from each group)
np.random.seed(0)
weights = np.random.rand(*dims)

# implement and solve problem
def maximum_npartite_matching(weights):

    # get dimensions from weights array
    dims = weights.shape

    # prepare auxiliary variables
    grid = [range(dim) for dim in dims]
    varx = itertools.product(*grid)

    # initialize variables
    xxx = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('xxx', varx, cat=pulp.LpBinary)

    # initialize optimization problem
    problem = pulp.LpProblem('nD matching', pulp.LpMaximize)

    # set objective
    # sum_ijk... c_ijk... x_ijk...
    problem += pulp.lpSum([weights[iii] * xxx[iii] for iii in xxx])

    # set constraints
    # sum_i x_ijk... <= 1
    # sum_j x_ijk... <= 1
    # sum...
    for idi, dim in enumerate(dims):
        for idv in range(dim):
            gric = copy.deepcopy(grid)
            gric[idi] = [idv]
            vary = itertools.product(*gric)
            problem += pulp.lpSum(xxx[iii] for iii in vary) <= 1

    # solve problem
    problem.solve()

    # write binary variables to array
    rex = weights.copy() * 0
    for iii in xxx:
        rex[iii] = xxx[iii].value()

    # find optimal matching = path and path weights
    whr = np.where(rex)
    paths = np.array(whr).T
    pathw = weights[whr]

    # print paths (n columns) and corresponding weights (last column)
    result = np.vstack([paths.T, pathw]).T
    print(result)

    return whr

# run matching
whr = maximum_npartite_matching(weights)

# define function for plotting results as network
def plot_results(weights, whr):

    # create list of node positions for plotting and labeling
    pon = [(idi, idv) for idi, dim in enumerate(dims) for idv in range(dim)]
    # convert to dictionary
    pos = {tuple(poi): poi for poi in pon}

    # create empty graph
    graph = nx.empty_graph(len(pos))
    # rename labels according to plot position
    mapping = {idp: tuple(poi) for idp, poi in enumerate(pon)}
    graph = nx.relabel_nodes(graph, mapping)

    # set edges from maximum n-partite matching
    edges = []
    # loop over paths
    for whi in np.array(whr).T:
        weight = weights[tuple(np.array(whj) for whj in whi)]
        pairs = list(zip(whi[:-1], whi[1:]))
        # loop over consecutive node pairs along path
        for idp, (id0, id1) in enumerate(pairs):
            edges.append(((idp+0, id0), (idp+1, id1), {'weight': weight}))
    graph.add_edges_from(edges)

    # set path weights as edge widths for plotting
    width = np.array([edge['weight'] for id0, id1, edge in graph.edges(data=True)])
    width = 3.0*width/max(width)

    #plot network
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))
    obj = weights[whr].sum()
    plt.title('total matching weight = %.2f' % obj)
    nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos=pos, width=width, node_color='orange', node_size=700)
    plt.axis('off')

    return graph, pos

# run plotting
graph, pos = plot_results(weights, whr)
```